# Meteor and React Native - FileCollection Access

Tags: mongodb, react-native, file, meteor

i posted this question some time ago at the FilesCollection Github Repo (https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files), but I'll hope to reach out here anyone who is familiar with Meteor and React Native.

My problem is, that I'm not sure how to use a FilesCollection with React Native (RN) and Meteor.

I used the official Meteor guide to set up a RN app: https://guide.meteor.com/react-native.html

So i have access to `@meteorrn/core` but how is it now possible for me to access a FileCollection.

Usually you would do this with (on a non-RN-web app):

```js
import { FilesCollection } from "meteor/ostrio:files";
export const ImageDB = new FilesCollection(chosenSettings);
```

where `chosenSettings` are some settings might be e.g.

```js
const chosenSettings = {
  collectionName: "Images",
  allowClientCode: false,
  onBeforeUpload(file) {
    if (file.size <= 10485760 && /png|jpg|jpeg/i.test(file.extension)) {
      return true;
    }
    return "Please upload image, with size equal or less than 10MB";
  },
  storagePath: `${process.env.PWD}/images`,
};
```

However, with RN it is not possible to access `FilesCollection` from `meteor/ostrio:files` as I don't have any meteor relation here

With other collections I can use `Mongo.Collection` from `@meteorrn/core`, however this is not possible with FilesCollection:

```js
const collection = new Mongo.Collection("myCollection");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your final use-case? Do you need to get access to the docs in the files-collection and or do you want to generate the download links or do you want to upload new files?

Comment: @Jankapunkt At first i would like to access the link. Usually i do this with `relImage.link()` where relImage might be `let relImage = ImageDB.findOne({ _id: imageId });`. Of course this is not possible without the FileCollection.

Comment: Okay I asked the wrong question - how do you get your docs from the Meteor App into your RN app. Do you use pub/sub or a Meteor Method call?

Comment: I use pub/sub for this case as proposed by the meteor doc on RN (https://guide.meteor.com/react-native.html). So it is then fetched with using `withTracker` or `useTracker`

Answer (score 1):

There is no "out-of-the-box" solution, as there is no FilesCollection on the RN client available. However, you could create a workaround strategy using a Meteor method.

1. Create a publication for the FilesCollection's underlying collection:

*server*

```js
Meteor.publish('imagesForRN', function () {
  return ImageDB.collection.find({}) // note the Mongo.collection is accessible here
})
```

2. Create a Method to resolve links:

*server*

```js
Meteor.methods({
  resolveRNLinks ({ ids }) {
    return ImageDB.collection
      .find({ _id: { $in: ids}})
      .map(linkImage);
  }
})

const linkImage = function (fileRef) {
  const url = Images.link(fileRef, 'original', Meteor.absoluteUrl())
  return { _id: fileRef._id, url }
}
```

3. Get the URLS of the subscribed docs

This assumes you have subscribed to the Image Collection as shown in the guide.

*client*

```js
import Meteor from '@meteorrn/core'

const MyComponent = props => {
  const { loading, myTodoTasks } = this.props;

  useEffect(() => {
    const ids = myTodoTasks.map(doc => doc._id)
    // note, you should filter those ids, which you have already
    // resolved so you only call for the new ones
    Meteor.call('resolveRNLinks', { ids }, (err, urls) => {
      // store urls in state or ref, depending on your usecase
    })
  })
}
```

Resources

- https://github.com/TheRealNate/meteor-react-native
- https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/docs/collection.md
- https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files/blob/master/docs/link.md